# Insert into a table based on a value of a matching row

Tags: sql, postgresql

How would I perform an insert query, which uses the `matcher` column to figure out which `groupID` a row belongs to and use that `groupID` value on insertion. And if there's no matches-- create a new group. The latter case is easy to do with a separate query, but I wonder if those two can be combined.

### Initial groups table:

```
| groupID |  val  | matcher |
| :-----: | :---: | :-----: |
|   g1    |  v1   |    a    |
|   g1    |  v2   |    a    |
|   g2    |  v3   |    b    |
|   g2    |  v4   |    b    |
```

### New values

```
|  val  | matcher |
| :---: | :-----: |
|  v5   |    a    |
|  v6   |    a    |
|  v7   |    b    |
|  v8   |    c    |
|  v9   |    c    |
```

### After query:

```
| groupID |  val  | matcher |
| :-----: | :---: | :-----: |
|   g1    |  v1   |    a    |
|   g1    |  v2   |    a    |
|   g2    |  v3   |    b    |
|   g2    |  v4   |    b    |
|   g1    |  v5   |    a    |
|   g1    |  v6   |    a    |
|   g2    |  v7   |    b    |
|   g3    |  v8   |    c    |
|   g3    |  v9   |    c    |
```

### Explanation:

1. `v5` and `v6` have the same `matcher` as the values in `groupID` of `g1`, so they were inserted with the `g1` id
2. `v7` had the same `matcher` as the `g2` group, hence similarly it was inserted into that group
3. `v8` had no matches, so a new group `g3` was generated (the generated `groupID` doesn't have to be sequential)
4. `v9` had no matches in the initial table, but since it has the same matcher as `v8`, which previously created a group, it is inserted into `v8`'s group

### Pseudo-code

```py
for value in newvalues:
  existing = mygroups.findWhere(groupvalue.matcher == value.matcher)
  if existing != null:
    mygroups.insert({groupID: existing.groupID, val: value.val, matcher: value.matcher})
  else: 
    mygroups.insert({groupID: generated(), val: value.val, matcher: value.matcher})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand.  You just need to either match groups or create new ones.  I'm not going to be tied to your naming conventions -- that is a bit tricky.  In fact, I would just make the groups numbers rather than strings.

But this generates new groups:

```
with newvalues as (
      select 'v5' as val, 'a' as matcher union all
      select 'v6' as val, 'a' as matcher union all
      select 'v7' as val, 'b' as matcher union all
      select 'v8' as val, 'c' as matcher union all
      select 'v9' as val, 'c' as matcher
     )
select nv.*,
       coalesce(i.groupid,
                'new_group' || dense_rank() over (partition by i.groupid order by nv.matcher)::text
               ) as groupid
from newvalues nv left join
     initial i
     on nv.matcher = i.matcher;
```

And this inserts the values:

```
with newvalues as (
      select 'v5' as val, 'a' as matcher union all
      select 'v6' as val, 'a' as matcher union all
      select 'v7' as val, 'b' as matcher union all
      select 'v8' as val, 'c' as matcher union all
      select 'v9' as val, 'c' as matcher
     )
insert into initial (groupid, val, matcher)
    select coalesce(i.groupid,
                    'new_group' || dense_rank() over (partition by i.groupid order by nv.matcher)::text
                   ) as groupid,
           nv.val, nv.matcher
    from newvalues nv left join
         initial i
         on nv.matcher = i.matcher;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b30d5554f4e83f1fc63c44d48a1a48b8) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thats a cool solution, but the outcome has rows with duplicate `val` fields. Any way I can account for those? I know I can add a `DISTINCT`, but my dataset is quite large and I've heard there are some heavy performance issues that can come out of that.

Comment: @VolodymyrBobyr . . . Neither the data in your question nor in this answer has duplicates -- so this answers the question that you asked.  But if you want to ensure uniqueness, you should declare a `unique` constraint on the column.